# Change SwRevealViewController Icon Image on Click

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swrevealviewcontroller

[image]

I would like to change the SwRevealViewController SideMenu click button to this when I click it and back to normal on pressing it again.How is it possible?Where Should I change the code in SwRevealViewController.m file?

Comment: Why don't you change the icon when it is tapped (inside your frontVC i.e. which contains the button) and let the chips fall where they may?

Comment: I use barButtonitem here .. The action is perofrmed in SwRevealViewController's .m file.So I need to perform this action in its library itself,so that i can change it for all the ViewControllers at once.

Comment: Okay. Well `- (void)revealToggleAnimated:(BOOL)animated` is called inside the library when the position is toggled.

Answer (score 0):

Add **SWRevealViewControllerDelegate** to your viewcontroller and implement following method.

```
 revealViewController.delegate = self;

-(void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController didMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position

//check position here
if(position == FrontViewPositionLeft) {

// show normal button image (your menu view is hidden here)

}
else if(position == FrontViewPositionRight) {

  // Change button image here.
}
```

You can also change your button image inside this method in SWRevealViewController.m

```
- (void)_setFrontViewPosition:(FrontViewPosition)newPosition withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Comment: revealViewController.delegate = self; returns error

Comment: you can refer this link.
https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController
and explore RevealControllerStoryboardExample2

Comment: @AkhilJiji It should not be returning error. It should be giving a warning instead. To get rid of that warning, Make your viewcontroller to be delegate of SWRevealViewController.

Answer (score 0):

//View Did load add this
// Swift 4.2

func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()
  let leftMenuItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu"), style: .plain, target: revealViewController, action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)))
        navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(leftMenuItem, animated: true)

}