# swrevealviewcontrtoller change toggle button image when side menu open/close?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using `SWRevealViewContrtoller` for slide-out side menu in my app. Which is working fine. But I have an issue, how can I change side-bar button image when button clicked or user dragged side menu. I'm referring to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848671/change-swrevealviewcontroller-icon-image-on-click).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do following-

**Method 1** (as per your reference link):

In your `homeVC.m` set `SWRevealViewControllerDelegate` like

`@interface homeVC ()<SWRevealViewControllerDelegate>` and add in `viewDidLoad()`
 `self.revealViewController.delegate = self;`

then add this method-

```
-(void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController didMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position{

    //check position here

    if(position == FrontViewPositionLeft) {

        [self.sideBarButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"open.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //self.sideBarButton is your toggle button IBOutlet

    }
    else if(position == FrontViewPositionRight) {

        [self.sideBarButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}
```

**Method 2:**

In your `sideVC.m` `import`-

```
#import "homeVC.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
```

Now add `viewWillAppear()` and `viewWillDisappear()`-

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    homeVC *vc=(UserProfileViewController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
    [vc.sideBarButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    homeVC *vc=(UserProfileViewController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
    [vc.sideBarButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"open.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

difference between **Method1** and **Method2** is that, In **Method1** when `sideVC` done animation i.e. position set to `FrontViewPositionLeft` or `FrontViewPositionRight` than button image changes by clicking button or dragging view. But in **Method2** when `sideVC` start appearing button image change and when `sideVC` disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Try [FRDLivelyButton](https://github.com/sebastienwindal/FRDLivelyButton). In this library, you can change the UIBarButton image.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

add `<SWRevealViewControllerDelegate>`

set `self.revealViewController.delegate = self;`

```
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController willMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position{

    //change button image below.

    if(position == FrontViewPositionLeft) {

        //drawer close

    } else {

        //drawer open
    }
}
```

This works for me. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE Swift 3.0**
add **SWRevealViewControllerDelegate** 
in your **viewDidLoad()** add this

```
self.revealViewController().delegate = self
```

```
 func revealController(_ revealController: SWRevealViewController!, willMoveTo position: FrontViewPosition) {
    if position == FrontViewPosition.left {
        //drawer close
    }
    else {
       //drawer open
    }
}
```